# Postgres RLS policy to disable select

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I want to a postgres policy to disable `select` operation on the table.

for which I wrote following security policy

```
create policy "workspace_data_only"
on "public"."services_connected"
as restrictive
for all
to anon
using ((workspace_id = (((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::text, true))::json ->> 'workspace_id'::text))::bigint));

CREATE POLICY "rls_no_read"
  ON public.services_connected FOR SELECT
  to anon
  USING (FALSE);
```

but I am still able to query and get data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since you didn't share all the DDL for the table and it's policies, nor the content of your current setting, it's hard to help you. Did you use `ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY` to get started?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any policy at all if you want to disable `SELECT`. Anything that is not explicitly allowed by a row level security is forbidden.

Make sure that you enabled row level security for the table:

```
ALTER TABLE services_connected ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

If you still can `SELECT` from the table, your user must be exempt from row level security. There are several possible reasons for that:

1. The user is the owner of the table. You can force row level security for the table owner with

   ```
   ALTER TABLE services_connected FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
   ```
2. The user is a superuser. Superusers are always exempt from row level security.
3. The user was created with

   ```
   CREATE ROLE ... BYPASSRLS;
   ```
4. The configuration parameter `row_security` is disabled.